# Optimizing $\rm \frac{x^TAx}{c^T x}$ subject to $\rm1^T x = 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I need to optimize the following quadratic-over-linear objective:

$$
\frac{x^TAx}{c^T x}
$$

subject to

$$\mathbf{1}^Tx = 1$$

Where $A$ is a diagonal (with all positive entries ) matrix and $c$ (also with strictly positive entries ) and $x$ are vectors. $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all ones.

There is a problem in [Boyd and Vandenberghe book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook) that solves the unconstraint problem but the solution I have found is not constructive and I am not able to generalize to the constraint case.

I have tried to follow the standard approach, computing the gradient of the Lagrangian and making it equal to zero but I am not able to get the solution. I get stuck with some cubic matrix equation.

Do anybody know if this is a typical problem in any field??

By the way, I am trying to find a closed form solution because I need it to use somewhere else.

Comment: By positive you mean $c_i>0$ or $c_i\ge 0$ ?

Comment: [Matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \def\o{{\tt1}} \def\a{\lambda} \def\b{\ell}$

Use an unconstrained vector $w$ to construct $x$ such that it automatically satisfies the constraint. Treat its the length and direction as independent variables.
$$\eqalign{
\b &= \o:w\quad&\implies\quad&d\b&=\o:dw \\
x &= \b^{-1}w\quad&\implies\quad&dx&=\b^{-1}dw - w\b^{-2}d\b \\
 &&&&= \b^{-1}(I-x\o^T)\,dw \\
}$$
Consider the numerator/denominator of the objective function.
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= A:xx^T \quad&\implies d\alpha = 2Ax:dx \\
\beta &= c:x
 &\implies d\beta = c:dx \\
\a &= \beta^{-1}\alpha
 &\implies \beta\a = \alpha \\
}$$
In the above, a colon has been used to denote the inner product
$$A:B\;=\;{\rm Tr}(A^TB)\;=\;\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}$$
(which is also valid for vectors if you treat them as rectangular matrices)

Calculate the gradient of the objective function with respect to
the *unconstrained* variable by substituting the above fragments.
$$\eqalign{
d\a &= \beta^{-2}(\beta\,d\alpha-\alpha\,d\beta) \\
 &= \beta^{-1}(2Ax-\a c):dx \\
 &= \beta^{-1}(2Ax-\a c):\b^{-1}(I-x\o^T)\,dw \\
 &= (\beta\b)^{-1}(I-\o x^T)\,(2Ax-\a c):dw \\
\p{\a}{w} &= (\beta\b)^{-1}(I-\o x^T)\,(2Ax-\a c) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve.
$$\eqalign{
2Ax + \a\beta\o &= 2\alpha\o + \a c \\
2Ax - \a\beta\o &= \a c \\
\left(\tfrac 2\a A - \o c^T\right)x  &= c \quad
\implies x = \left(\tfrac 2\a A-\o c^T\right)^{-1}c \\
}$$
The Sherman-Morrison formula for the inverse of a rank-1 perturbation is
$$\eqalign{
\Big(B+uv^T\Big)^{-1} = B^{-1} - \frac{B^{-1}uv^TB^{-1}}{1+v^TB^{-1}u}
}$$
Substitute $B=\left(\tfrac 2\a A\right),\,u=\o,\,v=-c\;$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\Big(\tfrac 2\a A - \o c^T\Big)^{-1}
 &= \tfrac\a 2
\left(A^{-1} + \frac{A^{-1}\o c^TA^{-1}}{\tfrac 2\a-c^TA^{-1}\o}\right)
}$$
and to reduce clutter for the next calculation,
define the scalars
$$\theta=c^TA^{-1}c,\quad\rho=c^TA^{-1}\o,\quad\mu=\o^TA^{-1}\o$$
Now use the constraint to evaluate $\a\;$
(via a scalar quadratic equation).
$$\eqalign{
\o^Tx &= \tfrac\a 2 \left(\o^TA^{-1}c + \frac{\o^TA^{-1}\o\;c^TA^{-1}c}{\tfrac 2\a-\rho}\right) \\
2 &= \a\rho+\left(\frac{\a\theta\mu}{\tfrac 2\a-\rho}\right)\left(\frac \a\a\right) \\
0 &= (\theta\mu-\rho^2)\a^2 + 4\rho\a - 4 \\
\a_\pm &= \left(\frac{2}{\rho\pm\sqrt{\theta\mu}}\right) \\
}$$
Substituting yields two possible $x$ vectors
$$\eqalign{
x_\pm  &= \left(\frac{1}{\rho\pm\sqrt{\theta\mu}}\right)
A^{-1}\left(c\pm\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\mu}}\o\right) \\
x_\pm  &= \frac{A^{-1}c\pm\Big(\frac{c^TA^{-1}c}{\o^TA^{-1}\o}\Big)^{\frac 12}A^{-1}\o}{c^TA^{-1}\o\pm\Big((c^TA^{-1}c)\;(\o^TA^{-1}\o)\Big)^{\frac 12}} \\
}$$

Comment: I have not checked the solution because I have not working in this problem for over 6 years. But it looks good to me. I may have a look a it in the following days.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated the answer to avoid calculating pseudo-inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed this question!  One field where quadratic-over-linear appears is optimal transportation.  Check out this paper for one example:  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5784.pdf

Comment: @T.Bongers I agree with you in general. Though if I were to bet I would put money on arXiv surviving longer than Math.SE.

Comment: I would have posted it as a comment but apparently I need at least 50+ reputation to do so (why?).  Don't have time to write a full post but figured this answer was better than nothing.

Comment: @JustinSolomon It is well-known that optimal transport uses linear programming, but on what page of that article do they show "quadratic-over-linear" programming? I don't see it